# При повторном запуске PyCharm не запускается код

Tags: pycharm

Всем доброго времени суток. Не могли бы мне подсказать решение проблемы, сейчас я только учусь. Я написал код парсера в PyCharm, все вроде работает. Стоит же мне выйти из программы или сменить проект на новый, а затем зайти обратно код перестает выполняться. Точнее сказать он выполняется, программа пишет что в процессе не было ошибок, но собранные данные не отображаются. Приходиться заново создавать проект, переносить в него код и только после этого собранные данные вновь начинают отображаться. Может кто сталкивался с подобной проблемой.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [При повторном запуске PyCharm не запускается код](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1535278/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b2%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bc-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%83%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b5-pycharm-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%83%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4)

Comment: @Эникейщик ...и автор удалил не тот вопрос

Comment: @andreymal смешно 

Comment: Вопрос слишком общий. Нужна конкретика: как и из какой директории запускается программа, что выводит, что должно выводить. И код самой программы желательно. А пока можно гадать. Например что вы неправильно отлавливаете исключения или что запускаете программу не совсем одинаково.